# List indices must be integers or slices not str- HMM forward algorithm

Tags: python, nlp

i am trying to implement forward algorithm in order to calculate HMM. I am doing step by step and debug on every step but i am getting an error. Anyone can tell me what error is?

My code is:

```
states = ('Fever','Healthy')
end = 'F'
observation =('3','1','1','2','2','3','1','3')
start = {'Fever': 0.5, 'Healthy': 0.5}
trans_prob = {
   'Fever' : {'Fever': 0.8, 'Healthy': 0.1, 'F': 0.1},
   'Healthy' : {'Fever': 0.1, 'Healthy': 0.8, 'F': 0.1},
   }
em_prob = {
   'Fever' : {'1': 0.1, '2': 0.2, '3': 0.7},
   'Healthy' : {'1': 0.7, '2': 0.2, '3': 0.1},
   }
#lent = len(observation)
prev = []
for i, obs_i in enumerate(observation):
    curr = []
    for st in states:
        if i==0:
            prev_sum =start[st]*em_prob[st][obs_i]
        else:
            for i in trans_prob.keys():
                prev_sum = sum(prev[k]*transition_probability[i][st] for k in states)
                print (prev_sum)
```

It is giving me this error:

> > TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
> >          20         else:
> >          21             for i in trans_prob.keys():
> >     ---> 22                 prev_sum = sum(prev[k]*transition_probability[i][st] for k in states)
> >          23                 print (prev_sum)
>
> in (.0)
>        20         else:
>        21             for i in trans_prob.keys():
>   ---> 22                 prev_sum = sum(prev[k]*transition_probability[i][st] for k in states)
>        23                 print (prev_sum)
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: what is `prev` and what is `k` in that line?

Comment: prev is my previous state as any state either it is fever or healthy and k is for iteration between states

Comment: `prev` is a list, lists are indexed by integers, `k` is not an integer... `prev[k]` will therefore fail.

Comment: yes but i need prev to be my state it can be either cold or hot

Comment: Neither I, nor Python, care what you need the state to be <wink>.  All we're saying is that you cannot do `prev["Fever"]` or `prev["Healthy"]`, no matter how much you need to, since it is a TypeError in Python.  When you've fixed that problem, you'll run into a related problem -- you're not changing `prev` in the for loops, so e.g. `prev[0]` will give an IndexError.  There's some serious logic issues that you need to sort out here...

Comment: @thebjorn what do you suggest for this?

Comment: I don't even know what you're trying to do, so any suggestions would be simply guessing. If anything I would suggest writing out, as text, which problem you're attempting to solve, and how you're intending to solve the problem. Use the descriptions to as module and function docstrings, and write tests that verify that the functions you'll create do the right thing (i.e. create functions with descriptive names that do small parts of the problem, and assemble them to create a solution).

Comment: okay thank you i got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `i` is a string not integer in `prev_sum = sum(prev[k]*transition_probability[i][st] for k in states)`.

You make a for loop that iterates over they keys of `trans_prob`. But those keys are "Fever" and "Healthy" which are strings not integers. Because `transition_probability` is a list (apparently, I didn't see it in the code), you need an integer to access its elements.

You may be confused on two aspects. Either you think that `transition_probability` is a dictionary, or you think that `trans_prob.keys()` returns integers, not strings. The value you're looking for is probably `trans_prob.values()`, but even then, with your current dict structure, it'll return strings "Fever", "Healthy", "F".

**EDIT:** Ah, I see the other issue. You use the variable twice in iteration. Once in the topmost for loop, which DOES return an int (which is probably what you're looking for), and then once in the very inner loop, which returns strings. I'd suggest rewriting `for i in trans_prob.keys():` to `for curr_key in trans_prob.keys():`

Comment: `i` is an int (from `enumerate`).

Comment: Just saw that, and edited my answer. It's being overwritten by the inner loop where the error is coming from. I made the appropriate suggestion to fix the code.

Comment: i tried your suggested edit but it isn't working not even when i am using trans_prob.values()

Comment: Again, `trans_prb.values()` wouldn't work because it's still looping through strings since you have a nested dictionary. It's tough to give a suggestion without understand what the code is supposed to do. What exactly is `transition_probability`? A list or a dictionary? if it's a dictionary, then it seems like you wouldn't need to change anything beyond the `i` to `curr_key` for that line.

Comment: its a list which contains the probabilities its something like set structure

Comment: Then you need to make sure that `i` is an integer. Try printing it out right before to see what it is. Also, if it's a flat list, like `[1, 2, 3]` then the double access of `[i][st]` wouldn't make sense.